# HAProxy backend configuring to work with Public Certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, server, certificate, haproxy

I have HAproxy on Linux I have already configured it to work with the self-signed certificate. I have also cases where should be used Public certificates. How can I configure HAProxy backend to work with the server public certificate?

Comment: Could you please explain clearly ?

Comment: Sure. For example when I have a self-signed certificate on the server where my HAProxy should connect I have the following configuration in haproxy.cfg backend part:

backend Name
      server GW1 IP:443 check ssl verify required ca-file cert.pem

Where cert.pem contains all certificate chains and also Server self-signed certificates. Now I have the server that work with public certificates

Comment: For example, my server is google.com